# Required attribute in Data Annotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I'm using MVC 4 and Entity Framework 5 to build my website. To validate data in client side, I use Data Annotations. Here is my property in View Model:

```
public int Salary { get; set; }
```

As you can see, I don't put any annotation there. Also, in my database, the `Salary` column was marked as `Allow null`.

My problem is whenever I submit my form, the `ModelState` is invalid because of this property. It thinks that this property is required and display error on client side.

Do you know what causes the problem? Please help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are having is because the default constructor initializes the property to 0. If you want to allow nulls do this:`public int? Salary { get; set; }`